# Рейтинг товара на сайте vue

Tags: vue.js

```
<div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
 <img class='bestsellers-item__image' :src='item.photo.url' alt='image'>
 <ul class='part-rating__star-list'>
        <li 
          class='part-rating__star'
          v-for='(value, index) in item.rating'
          :key='index'
        >
          <img src='assets/shop/fill-star.svg' v-if='value'>
          <img src='assets/shop/blank-star.svg' v-else>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Проблема следующая. Имею массив items, перебираю его, дабы вывести товары (item), выводится картинка все ок, у каждого товара своя.
Но есть система рейтинга, item.rating. Выводит только у первого товара 2 звезды (заполненные), нужно, чтобы было 5 звезд, 2 заполнились и 3 остались пустыми.
У всех товаров свой рейтинг.
Не хватает знаний, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Мы просто перебираем цикл от 1...5 ( 5 итераций)

```
<div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
  <img class='bestsellers-item__image' :src='item.photo.url' alt='image'>
  <ul class='part-rating__star-list'>
    <li class='part-rating__star' v-for='i in 5'>
      <img src='assets/shop/fill-star.svg' v-if='item.rating >= i'>
      <img src='assets/shop/blank-star.svg' v-else>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Уже лучше, но у первого товара рейтинг 2, а выводит заполненную звезду только одну. 
На остальных товарах, как и надо, пусто. С чем может быть связано?
А, всё, нужно было поставить =>. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Комбинируем ответы ;)